# Reassign the space of Deleted elements to existing new elements in Array Flex

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, multidimensional-array

How to reassign the space of deleted elements to existing elements in an 2D array in Flex and remove duplicates in the same?
I have an array as

```
Asia India Chennai 100
Asia India Chennai 200
Asia India Calcutta 300
```

I need an output as :

```
India Chennai 100
India Chennai 200
India Calcutta 300
```

so that The Asia space is occupied by India.

Right now am removing the first column using "delete" command as :

```
delete arrname[g][0] where "g" is the length of the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for `shift` method of the Array.
`shift` method removes first element and shift remaining elements to the beginning.
For more complex removing tasks you can use `splice` function.

Just read this [Array documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html), there are lots of useful method in `Array` class.